# When rendering js.erb file, it renders layout with the javascript, is it a bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A workaround that I found was to explicitly state in controller

```
render :action => :some_action, :layout => false
```

otherwise JavaScript fails to work

Anyone found this problem or maybe something is wrong with my configuration...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Real solution: I had rhtml for layouts and rails was defaulting all templates to that layout. Once I renamed all rhtml to html.erb, it fixed the problem. Here is the article about this in detail: http://yehudakatz.com/2009/06/18/and-the-pending-tests-they-shall-pass/

Answer (score 2):

it's a normal behaviour. How he know that you don't want render this layout ?

You can avoid the layout to all of your js format in add in your ApplicationController

```
Class ApplicationController

  layout :no_in_js_format

  def no_in_js_format
    if request.format == :js
      return nil
    else
      return 'application
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why would you ever want layout be rendered when rendering js.erb? And it appears it did not render layout in 2.X Versions.  But your solution is a good hack until they fix that =)

Comment: add a bug on Bugtracker to Rails can be a good solution if you think it's not a good feature

Comment: Real solution: I had rhtml for layouts and rails was defaulting all templates to that layout.  Once I renamed all rhtml to html.erb, it fixed the problem. Here is the article about this in detail: http://yehudakatz.com/2009/06/18/and-the-pending-tests-they-shall-pass/